# conversion - ASCII hex to float in c++

Tags: c++

I have a string containing, for example "3F800000".

This is a hexadecimal representation of the float 1.0  Only I can't seem to find any convenient way of making this conversion in C++.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming 32-bit `int` and `float`,

```
unsigned int x;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << "3F800000";
ss >> x;
return reinterpret_cast<float&>(x);
```

Comment: @ardiyu07: "3F800000" is the binary representation "1.0" in IEEE-754's `binary32`.  What the heck does "3F800000.24" mean?

Comment: This works, but it breaks strict aliasing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Comment: @ephemient C99 allows floating point hex, it allows a double to be represented without losing information (it came as a surprise to me aswell)

Comment: @Martin @ardiyu07: Floating-point hex is quite different from the bit-wise layout of IEEE 754.  For example, "1.0" would simply be "0x1.0".

Comment: @ephemient - true, I was just pointing out that "3F800000.24" is valid in C99, of course it has no similarity with the contents of a double in memory

Comment: @Martin: 3F800000.24 isn't a valid hex floating literal.  0x3F800000.24, on the other hand, is.

Comment: @ephemient - doing embedded wire protocol stuff at the moment. So I'm seeing 0x in front of my eyes!

Answer (score 1):

A newer variant, profiting from C++20 and `std::bit_cast` (`#include <bit>` for):

```
static_assert(sizeof(unsigned long) == sizeof(float));
// actually we don't need, std::bit_cast cares for as well
// as long as we let deduce the second template parameter
// from the function argument

auto bitPattern = std::strtoul("3F800000", nullptr, 16);
// or using std::stringstream, sscanf, whichever you prefer...

float value = std::bit_cast<float>(bitPattern);
```

In contrast to the other answers this is fully legal (not violating strict aliasing rules).

If C++20 is not available we still can use `memcpy` to legally copy the bit representation from the integral into the floating point variable (as done e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65920107/c-convert-4-hex-values-to-float)), or, if we are willing to use C in parallel, use a `union` for type-punning, but this must occur in a C-source as it wouldn't be legal in C++ either.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is:

```
int main() {
    std::string hexString = "3f9d70a4";
    auto long_val = std::stoul(hexString, nullptr, 16);
    cout << *reinterpret_cast<float *>(&long_val);
}
```

The above code may not work in some compile environments. The below code may work.

```
union U {
  uint64_t val;
  float f;
};
auto long_val = std::stoul(hexString, nullptr, 16);
U u = { long_val };
std::cout << u.f;
```

If the above code does not work in your compile environment, try memcpy

```
float f;
std::memcpy(&f, &long_val, sizeof f);
```

Comment: Violating strict aliasing rules just as the other answer...

Comment: Modified answer as 1) did not work in my environment, but 2) union did work in my environment.