# C++ Convert 4 Hex Values to Float

Tags: c++, hex

I am trying to convert 4 hexadecimal values to a float.

The hex values are for example `3F A0 00 00`. In binary representation they would correspond to `00111111 10100000 00000000 00000000`. If these 4 binary values are interpreted as one 32-bit float (accordingly to IEEE754) the decimal value of the float should be 1,25.

How to automatically make the conversion from hex values to decimal float in C++ (I am using Qt as Framework)?

Comment: Do you have the values in an array? You can memcpy them into the float, but don't forget the endianess: https://ideone.com/AKUkSE

Comment: yeah @CppProgrammer23 is right. Your question is a bit unclear.
Do you want to reinterpret 4byte of memory to be a float? Are your hex values stings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned char bytes[] = {0x3F, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00};
    
    uint32_t x = bytes[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < std::size(bytes); ++i) x = (x << 8) | bytes[i];

    static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t), "Float and uint32_t size dont match. Check another int type");
    
    float f{};
    memcpy(&f, &x, sizeof(x));
    // or since C++20 if available: float f = std::bit_cast<float>(x)
    
    cout << "f = " << f << endl;
}
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd6ad67ad45cd9dd)

Comment: Note that this program interprets that bytes in big endian order.

Comment: OP didn't say what order in which they want to interpret the bytes. Edit: Oh, they said that they want the value to be 1.25. Then they seem to want big endian indeed.

Comment: I think he did implicitelly .. his binary representation of those float value correspond to the bytes in BE order.

Comment: Slightly nicer C++20 alternative: `float f = std::bit_cast<float>(x);`

Comment: Also, to avoid magic numbers, I recommend as loop end condition: `i < std::size(bytes)`

Comment: Wow thank you so much for this fast answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have two possible values stored in that array (`5.74855e-41` and `1.25`) if your implementation uses 24 digit IEEE 754 floats - so you definitely need to deal with endianess.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <bit>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559 &&
                  std::numeric_limits<float>::digits == 24,
                  "Only 24 digit IEEE 754 floats supported");

    unsigned char src[] = {0x3F, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00};
    float dest;

    if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::little) {
        // swap the byte order
        std::reverse(std::begin(src), std::end(src));
    }

    std::memcpy(&dest, src, sizeof(float));
    
    std::cout << dest << '\n';    // prints 1.25
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jMEq5G)

Answer (score -1):

```c
float Uint32ToFloat(uint32_t data)
{
    float returnData = 0.0;

    static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t), "Float and uint32_t size dont match. Check another int type");
    memcpy(&returnData, &data, sizeof(data));
    return returnData;
}
```

Comment: I cannot see how this adds anything to the accepted answer

Comment: data is uint32 hex in memory. when you return a float, it handled by machine . similar  as casting.

Comment: Yes, but what does it add to the accepted answer? StPiere has already explained that.